# How to remove a particular shape from Google Maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I created some shapes on my Google Maps in Android, and on a button click, I want to remove a particular one.

On the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon#remove%28%29), I found this:

> public void remove ()
>
> Removes the polygon from the map.

I used this code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
          if (shape != null)
          {
            shape.remove();
            Log.w("DEBUG", "Shape removed");
          }
        }
```

Nothing happens, the shape is still there. What else should I use?

Comment: if you tap on the shape multiple times does the shape finally disappear? It could be that the shape is being added to the map multiple times. I had the same problem when trying to remove markers. Just a thought since I had a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, you were correct. I added the shape multiple times. If you move your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you tap on the shape multiple times does the shape finally disappear? It could be that the shape is being added to the map multiple times. I had the same problem when trying to remove markers. Just a thought since I had a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have already seen this web but just in case, i recommend you to look at this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes

You have to create and object of the following types: `Polyline`, `Polygon`, `Circle` and then, you can add them to the instance of your map.

```
// Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
    .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
    .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

After that, you can remove elements from the `myMap` object with `myMap.clear()`.

Hope this help you.

Comment: The problem with your advice is that it clears the entire map, so my other shapes disappear as well. So I need to use the remove function.

Answer (score -1):

Polygon Has a Method remove() to remove Polygon from Map